# Delete and Update List of Objects in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, edit

I have a form that has an input section at the top of the page and in the bottom half it displays a list of the objects that were added.  I need to be able to Edit and Delete these objects and I'm not sure where to start or how to do it.

This code display the list of objects.

```
                @if (Model.ListOfRecipients != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfRecipients.Count; i++)
                {

                <div class='recipient-wrapper'>
                    <div class='decision_block'>
                        <table class='recipient'>
                            <tr>
                                <td class='recipient-title'>
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId)
                                    <h3>
                                        @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientName)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientName)
                                    </h3>

                                    <div class='delivery-type'>
                                        Delivery Type: @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].DeliveryType)
                                                       @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].DeliveryType)
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class='na express'>
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].ExpressIndicator)
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].ExpressIndicator)
                                </td>
                                <td class='quantity'>
                                    <h3>
                                      Qty @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].Quantity)
                                          @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfRecipients[i].Quantity)
                                    </h3>
                                </td>
                                <td class='action'>
                                    <input class='button edit_recipient' type='button' value='Edit' />
                                    <input class='button delete_recipient' type='button' value='Delete' />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                            <input class='button update_recipient' type='button' value='Update' />
                            <a class='cancel_update' href='#'>Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write Edit and Delete action methods in your controller and then set your two buttons to call the appropriate method.

The code for the action methods will depend on several factors that may to broad to address here.

Using Razor Syntax -- sorry the others were using wrong markup:(

```
<input class='button edit_recipient' type='button' value='Edit' 
       onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Controller", new { id = Model.Id } )'" />
```

Comment: I've added a delete method in the controller that takes the object id as a parameter (I've added the object id as a hidden filed don't think its in my code above).  how do i get the delete button to send the id for the correct object ?

Comment: i think i need something like this for the delete  @Html.ActionLink("Recipients", MVC.Recipients.Delete(model=>model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId)

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald Edited my answer with a parameter included

Comment: Just realized I'm giving code in aspx engine and you're using razor.  Let me know if you need translation.

Comment: ActionLink would work as well, however make sure you use proper overload.  eg add null parameter to link in your comment.

Comment: @RonaldMcDonald Edited answer with razor syntax

Comment: I think i got it     @Html.ActionLink("Delete this recipient","Delete",new {id=Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId})

Comment: You may need a null at the end of that link definition.  If it gives you any trouble passing the parameter, construct the link like so:  @Html.ActionLink("Delete this recipient","Delete",new {id=Model.ListOfRecipients[i].RecipientId}, null)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a delete controller and an edit controller and in the above view have a  beside each one that has a delete and edit which recieves the objects id and each button goes to it's own view where they can edit or delete